# Is there a bug in IsomorphicSubgraphQ?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

***Version: Mathematica 13.0***

`IsomorphicSubgraphQ` is used to determine whether a graph has a subgraph  isomorphic to another graph. It was introduced by *Mathematica 13*. But it seems that  there is a bug in IsomorphicSubgraphQ.

```
G1 = Graph[
  ImportString["W|tNHEpCKoh`@@Po_WHB@CKC?WGO{G?KKCB`?OMG?_y_?Sn", 
   "Graph6"], VertexLabels -> Automatic];
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The graph below is a subgraph of the graph above.

```
subG1 = 
 Graph[ImportString["SsCAJ?`K?O`?@@@??WG@B?M??K??EG??{", "Graph6"], 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic];
```

[image]

But here's the “surprise”：

```
IsomorphicSubgraphQ[subG1, G1]
```

> `False`

`IGSubisomorphicQ` in **IGraphM** backpack gives the right answer: True.

```
<< IGraphM`
IGSubisomorphicQ[subG1, G1]
```

> `True`

Comment: I have Mathematica 13.0 version too but it returned me `True`. Isn't it an error on your side?

Comment: That's weird. Are you running on the Windows version?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10. Restart kernel and try again.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thanks. I tried your way and it didn't work. Maybe some of the files were corrupted. I don't know why, I updated it to 13.1, now it's OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK in version 13.1 on Windows 10:

```
G1 = Graph[ImportString["W|tNHEpCKoh`@@Po_WHB@CKC?WGO{G?KKCB`?OMG?_y_?Sn", 
"Graph6"], VertexLabels -> Automatic]
subG1 = Graph[ImportString["SsCAJ?`K?O`?@@@??WG@B?M??K??EG??{", "Graph6"], 
VertexLabels -> Automatic]
IsomorphicSubgraphQ[subG1, G1]
```

> `True`

Comment: Thanks for telling, it seems to be fixed in the new version. I did not see any any record of it being fixed  on the new 13.1 feature though.